# IntegrationServicesCatalog doesn't allow to create SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to create ssisdb on sql 2017 instance, i have configured clr , but for some reason the option to create SSISDB is not showing. Please see attachment and help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0mUN.png)

Comment: It's hard to tell if the screenshot is just cropped or is the problem that you don't see the OK and Cancel buttons. At this point, it looks like you just need to click OK to create SSISDB. If the problem is that you don't see OK, try expanding your window.

Comment: The real problem is that i can't see ok and cancel buttons , and even after i type password also it doesn't help. But i have managed to create ssisdb using powershell. i don't understand why these buttons are not showing when i try through SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had similar issues with several kinds of MS products like SSIS or SSMS, the OK or other buttons not showing, also users couldnt see values or filters in Power BI etc.

In these cases it was a display issue. Try display it on a larger monitor, try changing screen resolution, or move the box further up or try and resize the box in which the buttons should be in.

I also had cases where I couldnt see any buttons but they were displaying when a colleague set it up on his computer, so maybe you could ask a colleague if he/she can see the buttons.